# Compiling and testing an Android library project

Tags: java, android, android-library

Is it possible to compile and test an Android library project independently from a standard Android project?

I have an app which I have already released for free on Google Play. Now I want to create a premium paid app with additional features. I found out that the best way to do this is by creating a library project with the shared code and resources and then override them in two separate Android projects.

I would like to compile and test common code in the library independently from the "lite" and "premium" projects as to reduce the amount of time writing test code and, perhaps more importantly, running it.

The problem I encountered is that when I compile the test project, I get several "constant expression required" errors when I use values from `R.id` as a `case` for a `switch` statement. Looking at the generated `R.java` file I see that these values are declared as `static int`s. When I have the exact same code in a standard Android project, the same variables in `R.id` are declared as `static final int`s instead.

Is there a way to resolve this issue without resorting to `if...else if...else` chains?